# Make acts_as_paranoid finders exclude "deleted" objects conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, acts-as-paranoid

Normally, with acts_as_paranoid, when you use a finder such as `find` or `where`, it excludes entries that have a `deleted_at` (or whatever you named your delete column) value other than null. However, I have created a user permission that allows users to view and manipulate even "deleted" (see: hidden) entities in the database. Thing is, as it stands, I will need to check for the permission every time I want to run `find`, or `where`, or what-have-you, and if you have that permission use `with_deleted` as opposed to having one place that checks to see if the acts_as_paranoid logic should even work to begin with, and always adding `with_deleted` when that logic shouldn't.

Is there any way to accomplish this, or something similar to it, to make it all DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). This allows you to define abilities.
You can then define:

```
if user.admin?
  can :manage, User.with_deleted
else
  can :manage, User
end
```

Then you can select in the controller, using:

```
User.accessible_by(current_ability)
```